# Does choosing a basis for vector space $V$ canonically define matrix forms of elements in $\operatorname{End}(\operatorname{End}(V))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Does choosing a basis for vector space $V$ canonically define matrix forms of elements in $End(End(V))$?

Obviously choosing a basis gives a matrix form for every matrix in $\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}\End(V)$, but what can be said about $\End(\End(V))$? This question came across my mind whilst pondering the matrix form of $ad(x)$ for $x \in L$ for some Lie algebra $L \subset gl(n,F)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V$ is finite-dimensional, a basis $\{ e_i \}$ of $V$ canonically determines a dual basis $\{ f_i \}$ of $V^{\ast}$ (defined by the condition $f_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$), which in turn determines the "matrix" basis $\{ e_i \otimes f_j \}$ of $V \otimes V^{\ast} \cong \text{End}(V)$. Now you can repeat this construction with the "matrix" basis, and you'll get a basis of

$$\text{End}(\text{End}(V)) \cong \text{End}(V) \otimes \text{End}(V)^{\ast} \cong (V \otimes V^{\ast}) \otimes (V^{\ast} \otimes V)$$

which should work out to be $\{ e_i \otimes f_j \otimes f_k \otimes e_{\ell} \}$.